# How to resuse properties from the PageModel after an OnPost call?

Tags: razor, view, model, razor-pages

I'm working on a project without a DB as of now. I have a model with an `OnGet` method that assigns values to some properties on page load.

For the view page I have a form that needs a dummy `OnPost` method that does... whatever (reload the page, or anything). The problem is that when submitting the form, the properties don't repopulate and the data doesn't persist, so the application crashes.

What would be a useful way to repopulate the data in the `OnPost` method? Two ways would be:

1. Call `OnGet` inside `OnPost`:

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    this.OnGet();
}
```

But this seems... weird...

2. Redefine the values I had initially in `OnGet` inside `OnPost`

```cs
public void OnPost()
{
    PropertyOne = "First Value";
    PropertyTwo = "Second Value";
}
```

What other choices do I have here?

Answer (score 0):

The most common approach that you will likely see is the second approach where you explicitly initialise property values in the `OnPost` method. Calling `OnGet` in the `OnPost` method is more likely to have unwanted side effects in real life applications. So the alternative is to create a private method that initialises properties or performs other tasks that are needed for any request, regardless of the HTTP request verb:

```
private async Task DoStuff()
{
    Prop1 = await db.Something();
    Prop2 = await db.SomethingElse()
}

public async Task OnGet()
{
    await DoStuff();
}

public async Task OnPost()
{
    await DoStuff();
}
```